# How can I use controls.update(); with PointerLockControls.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, controls, typeerror

When I am using the snippet of code below I have been told to use the controls.update(); command, but I get an error

Uncaught TypeError: controls.update is not a function at animate

I looked through PointerLockControls.js and OrbitControls.js and I noticed that Orbit has an update() function and Pointer does not, last I checked having the controls update every frame was important, how am I to get around this issue?

```
var dt = 1/60;
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(controls.enabled) {
    world.step(dt);

    //update ball positions
    for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
      ballMeshes[i].position.copy(balls[i].position);
      ballMeshes[i].quaternion.copy(balls[i].quaternion);
    }

    //update box positions
    for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
      boxMeshes[i].position.copy(boxes[i].position);
      boxMeshes[i].quaternion.copy(boxes[i].position);
    }
  }

  controls.update(Date.now()-time);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  time = Date.now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been told to use the controls.update() command,

Interesting, who told you that^^? `PointerLockControls` does not have an update method because it just performs simple event handling. Although `OrbitControls` has an update method, you only have to call it if damping or auto-rotation is enabled. Why? Because when one of these option is active, it needs to update the camera even if not events like `mousemove` or `touchmove` were fired.

Answer (score 0):

can you not use orbitcontrols and pointerlockcontrols together? then it will take update from orbit since pointerlock does not have it.